# Iterating over a multi-dimensional json in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, iteration

Sorry for posting incorrect format, Hope now my query is clear. 
I am parsing a JSON, which is basically a config file for my framework.
This is how it looks:
[My JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfaYP.jpg)
[JSON Random Field's values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO2CQ.jpg)

My Code :

```
def makeCombination():
data = schemaConfig["PostData"]
out_json = []
for v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6 in product(data['size']['testing_type']['random'], data['start_index']['testing_type']['random'], data['campaign_sub_type']['testing_type']['random'], data['campaign_type']['testing_type']['random'], data['api_key']['testing_type']['random'], data['project_id']['testing_type']['random']):
    out_json.append({'size': v1,'start_index': v2,'campaign_sub_type': v3,'campaign_type': v4,'api_key': v5, 'project_key': v6})
    return out_json


def runRegressionFunc():
randomList = makeCombination()
tempOutList = list()
for comb in randomList:
    tempDoc = dict()
    for funcName in comb:
        (key, val) = callOtherClasses(funcName)
        tempDoc[key] = val
    tempOutList.append(tempDoc)

return tempOutList
```

I want to get all possible combinations from "random" of all fields in makeCombination() and return this to runRegressionFunc().

P.S. I am new to coding world :)

Comment: Can you post an example of your code? - How are you parsing this data?

Comment: Your json has syntax errors.

Comment: Updated my query, hope now I am able to highlight my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your json was incorrect. After fixing the syntax, you can use `itertools.product` to get all combinations of the contents of `api_key` and `project_key` and create a new list of dicts, with the info you want.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> import pprint
>>>
>>> json_data = {"PostData" : {
... "api_key": {
...   "data_type": "String",
...   "testing_type": {
...     "random": [
...       "veryShortString",
...       "shortString",
...       "longString"
...       ]}},
... 
...  "project_key": {
...   "data_type": "String",
...   "testing_type": {
...     "random": [
...       "veryShortString",
...       "shortString",
...       "longString"
...       ]}}}}
>>>
>>> data = json_data['PostData']
>>> out_json = []
>>> for v1, v2 in product(data['api_key']['testing_type']['random'], data['project_key']['testing_type']['random']):
...      out_json.append({'api_key' : v1, 'project_key' : v2 })
... 
>>>
>>> pprint.pprint(out_json)
[{'api_key': 'veryShortString', 'project_key': 'veryShortString'},
 {'api_key': 'veryShortString', 'project_key': 'shortString'},
 {'api_key': 'veryShortString', 'project_key': 'longString'},
 {'api_key': 'shortString', 'project_key': 'veryShortString'},
 {'api_key': 'shortString', 'project_key': 'shortString'},
 {'api_key': 'shortString', 'project_key': 'longString'},
 {'api_key': 'longString', 'project_key': 'veryShortString'},
 {'api_key': 'longString', 'project_key': 'shortString'},
 {'api_key': 'longString', 'project_key': 'longString'}]
```

Comment: That is not what he/she is asking for. It's not a simple `zip` that you need to do, but take into account all combinations

Comment: Thanks for your response, tried your way but unable to get the expected result. I have updated my query, please see if you can help.

Comment: @RishabhSingh All you need to do is grab the other items and pass all of them to itertools.product. Please try it out.

Comment: @Coldspeed Thanks, I was able to get all the combinations with few changes and using itertools.product on my list.

Comment: @RishabhSingh Glad to hear. Cheers!